# C# WebAPI Thread Aborting when Sharing Data Access Logic

Tags: c#, multithreading, webapi, blockingcollection, threadabortexception

I'm getting the following error on my C# Web API: "Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in System.Data.dll
Thread was being aborted".  I have a long running process on one thread using my data access logic class to get and update records being process.  Meanwhile a user submits another group to process which has need of the same data access logic class, thus resulting in the error.  Here is a rough sketch of what I'm doing.

**WebAPI Class**:

```
public IHttpActionResult OkToProcess(string groupNameToProcess)
{
    var logic = GetLogic();
    //Gets All Unprocessed Records and Adds them to Blocking Queue
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dataAccessLogic.LoadAndProcess(groupNameToProcess);
}

public IHttpActionResult AddToProcess(int recordIdToProcess)
{
    StaticProcessingFactory.AddToQueue(recordIdToProcess);
}
```

**StaticProcessingFactory**

```
internal static ConcurrentDictionary<ApplicationEnvironment, Logic> correctors = new ConcurrentDictionary<ApplicationEnvironment, Logic>();
        internal static BlockingCollection<CorrectionMessage> MessageQueue = new BlockingCollection<Message>(2000);

public void StartService(){
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LoadService());
}

public void LoadService(){
    var logic = GetLogic();
    if(isFirstGroupOkToProcessAsPerTextFileLog())
         logic.LoadAndProcess("FirstGroup");
    if(isSeconddGroupOkToProcessAsPerTextFileLog())
         logic.LoadAndProcess("SecondGroup");
}

public static GetLogic(){
     var sqlConnectionFactory = Tools.GetSqlConnectionFactory();
     string environment = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultApplicationEnvironment"];
     ApplicationEnvironment applicationEnvironment = 
         ApplicationEnvironmentExtensions.ToApplicationEnvironment(environment);
     return correctors.GetOrAdd(applicationEnvironment, new Logic(sqlConnectionFactory ));
}

        public static void AddToQueue(Message message, bool completeAdding = true)
        {
            if (MessageQueue.IsAddingCompleted)
                MessageQueue = new BlockingCollection<Message>();

            if (completeAdding && message.ProcessImmediately)
                StartQueue(message);
            else
                MessageQueue.Add(message);
        }

     public static void StartQueue(Message message = null)
     {
          if (message != null)
            { 
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.ID))
                    MessageQueue.Add(message);
                Logic logic = GetLogic(message.Environment);

                try
                {
                    var messages = MessageQueue.TakeWhile(x => logic.IsPartOfGroup(x.GroupName, message.GroupName));
                    if (messages.Count() > 0)
                        MessageQueue.CompleteAdding();
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (var msg in messages)
                    {
                        i++;
                        Process(msg);
                    }
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException) { MessageQueue.CompleteAdding(); }

            }
     }

     public static void Process(Message message)
     {
         Var logic = GetLogic(message.Environment);
         var record = logic.GetRecord(message.ID);
         record.Status = Status.Processed;
         logic.Save(record);
     }
```

**Logic Class**

```
private readonly DataAccess DataAccess;

public Logic(SqlConnectionFactory factory)
{
     DataAccess = new DataAcess(factory);
}

public void LoadAndProcess(string groupName)
{
     var groups = DataAccess.GetGroups();
     var records = DataAccess.GetRecordsReadyToProcess(groups);
     for(int i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
            {
                Message message = new Message();
                message.Enviornment = environment.ToString();
                message.ID = records[i].ID;
                message.User = user;
                message.Group = groupName;
                message.ProcessImmediately = true;

                StaticProcessingFactory.AddToQueue(message, i + 1 == records.Count);
            }
}
```

**Any ideas how I might ensure that all traffic from all threads have access to the Data Access Logic without threads being systematically aborted?**

Comment: Is the error actually *"Thread was being aborted"* - that wording seems a little stilted?  Does it show up as an exception (if so, you should mention that)?  Have you looked at the inner exception property?  If your long running thread has an unhandled exception, it will likely abort.

Comment: Yes.  It shows up as: "Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in System.Data.dll
Thread was being aborted."

Comment: I've edited it to include the more precise exception.

Comment: Is there an inner exception? If so, what does the stack look like?

Comment: No Inner Exception or Stack Trace.